# Query Azure SQL DB through API using Java

Tags: java, api, azure-sql-database, firewall, adal

I am trying to access Azure SQL Database , using java. Our code will be staying in MS Appcenter. Since the DB firewall is not letting the Appcenter to access the database, I am trying to use API. Can someone help me provide me steps / sample code to get it started?

Comment: please ref:[Quickstart: Use Java to query a database in Azure SQL Database or Azure SQL Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-java?tabs=windows). Is this you want?

Comment: Did you set Allow Azure services and resources to access this server on in SQL database filrewall?

Answer (score 1):

1. You will need to enable firewall of Azure SQL Database to allow
   connection from azure (as you are hosting it in the MS Appcenter).
   In order to do that read [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-configure#connections-from-inside-azure)
2. Once that is enabled, you can use documentation [Quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-java?tabs=windows) to see how you can connect from it from application. Above document is in java language but you can find similar document for other languages also.